# sqlite Insert statement value contains select clause : is it possible

Tags: sqlite

I want to insert the records that time want to get the visitNo from other table & execute.only one fileds.

We can do it in separate separate query(that means getting visitNo from table & passing to other(insert) query).But I want to do it one query.without writting two query.

```
  INSERT INTO  wmVisitHeader (VisitNumber, ExecutiveCode, BusinessUnit, RouteCode, StartTime, UploadedBy, VisitDate, TerritoryCode) 
  VALUES(Select NextVisitNo from WMTransactionControl,'TEST001','MASS','VRT002','11:15' ,'TEST001','8/25/11 11:15' ,'0001')
```

like this ... i want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO  wmVisitHeader (VisitNumber, ExecutiveCode, BusinessUnit, RouteCode, StartTime, UploadedBy, VisitDate, TerritoryCode) 
VALUES((Select NextVisitNo from WMTransactionControl),'TEST001','MASS','VRT002','11:15' ,'TEST001','8/25/11 11:15' ,'0001')
```